# Referencing SQL temporary table in R Studio

Tags: sql-server, r

I have run a query creating a temporary table in SQL that I am now trying to analyze in R Studio. I don't think I am properly pulling the data into R Studio, and as a result, I cannot perform calculations on it. I am first running:

```
cn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection="Driver={SQLServer};
      server=servername;database=databasename;trusted_connection=yes;")
new_data<-sqlQuery(cn,"SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM #TempDatabaseName")
```

After I run this code, new_data appears under Values in the R Environment, not under Data. Then, when I run:

```
new_reg<-lm(yvar~xvar,data=new_data)
```

I get the following error:

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character'

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What do you get when you enter `class(new_data)` after running your first code block above? If it is `"character"`, enter `new_data` and you should see an SQL error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `lm` function is looking for a `data.frame`. Try running your query with `as.data.frame()`.

```
cn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection="Driver={SQLServer};
    server=servername;database=databasename;trusted_connection=yes;") 
    new_data<-as.data.frame(sqlQuery(cn,"SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM 
    #TempDatabaseName"))

new_reg<-lm(yvar~xvar,data=new_data)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking a look, scribbles and @BenBarnes. I am now getting the following error: 42S02 208 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name '#LastWithDefaultPctLR'. [RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM #LastWithDefaultPctLR'

Comment: @OGo238, then it looks like R doesn't see the temporary table that you created. If you create the SQL table from R, that should work.

Comment: @BenBarnes would you happen to have any suggestions on how can I remedy the fact that R doesn't see my temporary table?

Comment: @OGo238 You'll need to create the temporary table from within R. Temp tables are specific to a process/session. When you create a temp table from another SQL Server session, it will invisible to R (or any other SQL Server session).